# How do I connect this css3 webkit animation to an element when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I know, a very simple question, but I don't know!

I have:

```
.touch img{
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```

How would I make that activate when someone clicks on the element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
 $('#click').click(function() {
    $('.touch img').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'scale(2)'})
 });
});
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it:

```
.touch img.clicked
```

And use the script:

```
$(".touch img").click(function(){this.addClass("clicked")});
```

Answer (score 0):

`active` is the psuedo class you're looking for.

```
.touch img:active{
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```